# How can I load a picture in a img tag from bytea field, using PHP?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

how can I load a picture in a img tag from bytea field, using php? I´m using postgresql database

What I have tried:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$con_qupos = pg_connect('host=192.168.60.254 dbname=dbqupos user=postgres password=12345') or die(pg_last_error());

// Get the bytea data
$res = pg_query('select foto from "schSuperCristian".articulo_foto where codigo_referencia='."'8711600305960'");
$raw = pg_fetch_result($res, 'foto');

// Convert to binary and send to the browser
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo pg_unescape_bytea($raw);
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this working?

Comment: Thank's , is working but could not load the image into an image tag instead of the header, i solved it in the following way <?php 
  // Connect to the database
  $con_qupos = pg_connect('host=192.168.60.254 dbname=dbqupos user=postgres password=12345') or die(pg_last_error());
  
  // Get the bytea data
  $res = pg_query('select foto from "schSuperCristian".articulo_foto where codigo_referencia='."'8711600305960'");  
  $raw = pg_fetch_result($res, 'foto');
  
  $img = "data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode(pg_unescape_bytea($raw));

  echo "<img src='$img' alt=''>" ;
?>